# trigger to update parents child id in another child object

Tags: apex

I am working on one trigger, I have below objects

1. SOW
2. Project
3. Project Role

SOW is having self lookup relationship, Project is having look up to SOW, Project role is having lookup to SOW.

When I create a role by selecting sow, then the Project field should get populated by Project Id which is connected to sow which is working fine.

Since sow is having a self lookup relationship, I will be having parent sow and child sow records, if I create any role to child sow then I want to populate project id that is related to parent sow to the role that is creating to child sow, which is not working.

Can anyone help me out with this issue here?

My class is below

```
public class RoleUpdateClass {
    public static void roleUpdate(List<Project_Role__c> allRoles){
        set<Id> sowId = new set<Id>();
        Map<Id,Id> projectMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for(Project_Role__c role : allRoles){
            if(role.SOW__c != null){
                sowId.add(role.SOW__c);
            }
        }
        for(Project__c project : [select Id,Name,SOW__c from Project__c where SOW__c IN: sowId]){
            projectMap.put(project.SOW__c, project.Id);
        }
        for(Project_Role__c p : allRoles){
            if(projectMap.containsKey(p.SOW__c)){
                p.Project__c = projectMap.get(p.SOW__c);
            }
    }
    }
    public static void crroleupdate(List<Project_Role__c> allroles){
        set<Id> CRsowId = new set<Id>();
        Map<Id,Id> crProjectMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for(Project_Role__c pro : allroles){
            CRsowId.add(pro.SOW__r.Related_SOW__c);
        }
        for(Project__c project : [select Id,Name,SOW__c from Project__c where SOW__c IN: CRsowId]){
            crProjectMap.put(project.SOW__c, project.Id);
        }
        for(Project_Role__c role : allroles){
            if(crProjectMap.containsKey(role.SOW__r.Related_SOW__c)){
                role.Project__c = crProjectMap.get(role.SOW__r.Related_SOW__c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidCheng, Did you mean this one: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309279/class-to-update-parent-id-in-grand-child?

Comment: @HengkyIlawan Yes, that's the one.  Harish why is your post is for the same problem as in the link?